# How to set character per line limit in word or excel or any other program?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm doing an application online and part of a section requires 7 lines of writing. However in each line it requires no more than 130 characters. I have done the 7 lines but some lines are over 130 characters and some under.
My question is using word/excel is there any way to automatically format the paragraph so that each line is 130 characters or less?

If another program is required please expand.
Thanks a lot :]

Comment: You could create a table that only has enough width for 130 characters, then set your font to monospaced and type away. Seems quite hacky to me though.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would achieve this:

[image: fixed width table]

Under Microsoft Word create a table that fits exactly 130 characters, then turn off the `Automatically resize to fit contents` options under `Table Properties`.

It's pretty hacky, but quick and easy to set up.

Comment: I like hacky if it gets the job done quick and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with Excel, you can use data validation in Excel.

see this article [Apply data validation to cells: Restrict data entry to text of a specified length](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx#BM4_6)

Comment: While the article you linked to may answer the question, it's better to include the important parts of your answer here and include the link for reference.